# launch angular app from GWT app

Tags: java, angular, gwt

Actually, I'm thinking to migrate a huge app from gwt to angular but the idea here is to migrate slowly   so I m wondering from the experts here, if is it possible to launch an angular app from the gwt menu (click event)? any idea how to do that?

Comment: Yes, you can use jsni to call a js method exposed by angular

Comment: @LuigiPolvani is it possible even with angular 2 ? any simple example available to follow ?